# IAxWinHostWindow CreateControl returns E_NOINTERFACE when trying to host WMP within a CAxWindow

Tags: c++, windows, activex, windows-ce, wmp

I am trying to embed a WMP control inside my Win32 App. 
I have followed the example code here: [Hosting the Windows Media Player Control in a Windows Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

However when I step through this example, the line:

```
hr = spHost->CreateControl(CComBSTR(_T("{6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6}")), m_wndView, 0);
```

returns E_NOINTERFACE;

The line:

```
hr = m_wndView.QueryHost(&spHost);
```

succeeds and seems to populate spHost correctly.

Here's the code:

```
CAxWindow m_wndView;
CComPtr<IObjectWithSite> spHostObject;
CComPtr<IAxWinHostWindow>  spHost;
CComBSTR classID = __uuidof(WindowsMediaPlayer);

RECT rcClient = { 0, 0, 560, 335 };
m_wndView.Create(m_hWnd, rcClient, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);

hr = m_wndView.QueryHost(&spHost);

if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    hr = spHost->CreateControl(classID, m_wndView, 0);  //E_NOINTERFACE
}

hr = m_wndView.QueryControl(&m_spPlayer);   //E_FAIL
```

Can anybody give me any idea as to why this happens?
Thanks.

**Edit**: The line that actually fails is this one inside the ActivateAx() function:

`hr = m_spOleObject->DoVerb(OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE, NULL, spClientSite, 0, m_hWnd, &m_rcPos);`

If anyone could shed any more light on this that would be great.

**Edit2**: Just noticed I get this spammed in my output window whilst i'm stepping through this code:

"**An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call**"
Any Ideas?

Comment: CAxWindow calls it in its constructor, adding another call to it in my code makes no difference. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Check the device registry to make sure the registered WMP GUID matches what you're using.

Comment: I think they do match as I can do a CoCreateInstance with the same GUID and it succeeds.. I will double check that though, thanks. edit: just checked and they do match.

Answer (score 1):

The code is right and works as is, and as suggested on MSDN page.

An problem exactly as described might come up if you your UI window is in MTA apartment, that is the thread you are running on was initialized with `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)`.

What is happening then, your WMP is instantiated on a side STA thread and its interface marshaled into your thread/apartment. Not every required interface can be transferred this way, so once you keep on initializing it some of the mandatory interfaces is missing...

WMP is using "Apartment" threading model, use it on STA threads.